# Why does .NET Framework overload for arrays and IEnumerable & params []?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

In .NET framework, there are some functions, which accept both `IEnumerable` and `Array` parameters, or `params Array` parameters.

Since `IEnumerable` would satisfy any calling code that provides an `Array`, **why is it implemented?**

`params Array` on the other hand doesn't replace `IEnumerable`, however, it replaces `Array.`

So in my view, only `IEnumerable` and `params Array` is required.

**Question:** What is the intention in a framework (like .NET) behind this? Is it downward compatibility in case the callee uses reflection?

---

**Example 1:**

```
File.WriteAllLines(string path, string[] contents);
--> File.WriteAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> contents);
```

**Example 2:**

```
Path.Combine(string path1, string path2);
Path.Combine(string path1, string path2, string path3);
Path.Combine(string path1, string path2, string path3, string path4);
--> Path.Combine(params string[] paths);
```

Comment: `params string[]` is no different than `string[] `. when you use `params` the compiler allows you to go with syntactic sugar. so `new[] {a,b,c}` and `a,b,c` would be compiled into same thing.

Answer (score 4):

For the **Example 1**: in this specific case, [the `string[]` is from .NET 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx), while [the `IEnumerable<string>` is from .NET 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx). The use of `IEnumerable<T>` has become "cool" after the introduction of LINQ (.NET 3.5), when `IEnumerable<T>` has gained a central position in .NET. Before that, arrays where the most used collection type (probably because in .NET 1.1 they were the only strongly typed base collection). Probably if they rewrote the .NET today, they wouldn't put the array version of the method.

For the **Example 2**, the fourth method requires an array, that is an additional object (creating an object is a cost... sometimes you try to remove this cost). For speed sake, some methods have multiple overloads that have the exact number and types of parameters that are used.

Note that there is a third case: methods where an array can speed up the method, because it can be re-read multiple times. You shouldn't re-read multiple times a `IEnumerable<T>`, because there is no guarantee that it can be re-read, or that re-reading it won't incur in a big cost.

Example: `string.Concat(string[])` vs `string.Concat(IEnumerable<T>)`. The first version can pre-calculate the total length of the new string and allocate the exact space necessary (so it will cycle the `string[]` twice, once to calculate the total `Length`, the second time to copy the `string`s to the new `string`). The second one must use a growing buffer, because it can read the `IEnumerable<T>` only once.

Comment: **Example 1:** I'm aware of generics not being available from the beginning. Is there a reason you should design frameworks to keep these overloads? Is it because of reflection?
**Example 2:** Looking at the reference source, there is a lot more performance optimization than one could imagine! Seems reasonable... Especially for buffer concatenation.

Comment: @bytecode77 You can't remove methods in newer versions of .NET, you would make it incompatible with older versions. It is a big breaking change to remove things. In .NET Core they are trying to trim a little the .NET Framework, but in the end they are readding many things, because otherwise no one would convert their old application to .NET Core (too many changes to do)